# In Spring web app deployed to tomcat server, catalina.properties file is automatically loaded and detected by spring. HOW?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat

When developing a spring based web app (and deploying to tomcat), we can put our configuration in several places. One of them is catalina.properties. I would like to know how catalina.properties file is made available to spring app. Is it tomcat who does this or spring who loads catalina.properties file? How spring knows from where to load configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat automatically makes any properties configured in `catalina.properties` available as system properties. Spring's `Environment` uses [a number of different sources for the properties that it contains](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-property-source-abstraction). One of those sources is the JVM's system properties. As a result, the properties specified in `catalina.properties` are available via Spring's `Environment`.